# How can I create a crontab in a Shell script

Tags: shell, cron

I have to automate my Crontab script and would like to insert some things in my Crontab file, I want to do that without interactive query and it should look like command:

```
crontab_admin.sh -add -s "15 9 * * *" -c "check_backup_include_list.sh" -u "USERNAME" -t "CRQ000000000000"

crontab_admin.sh -remove -s "15 9 * * *" -c "check_backup_include_list.sh" -u "USERNAME" -t "CRQ000000000000"
```

and it should look like this in crontab afterwards:

```
15 9 * * * $HOME/scripts/check_backup_include_list.sh
```

sry for my bad english

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not wise to operate directly with cron file. But you can add record with script like this:

```
crontab -l >/tmp/c1
echo '15 9 * * * /full/path/to/scripts/check_backup_include_list.sh' >>/tmp/c1
crontab /tmp/c1
```

If you want to remove particular record you can do for example with something like this:

```
crontab -l >/tmp/c1
grep -v check_backup_include_list.sh' /tmp/c1 > /tmp/c2
crontab /tmp/c2
```