# Have a script launch at a specific time based on data that script just accessed

Tags: python, cron

Here's what I'm trying to accomplish. I've got a Google Sheet that I populate with current astronomical, weather, and nautical information. The data comes from multiple sources. Most scripts run a prescribed time. For example sunrise/sunset data is gathered once a day. Current temperature and wind info is gathered every 15 minutes. I've set up crontab to run those. One of the data sets is the current tidal information -- is it rising or falling, by how much, and when does it change direction. Tides don't happen at the same time every day, so to keep the script current I run it every 15 minutes. That's overkill because tides change approximately every six hours.

Ideally I could run the script a minute or two around the next tide change to keep the sheet current. Is it possible to have a script update a row in the crontab? Is it advised? I'm sure there's an elegant way to do this, but it eludes me. If someone can point me in the right direction, I'll do the legwork. I'm not asking for code. A simple "try this, it worked for me" will do.

Comment: If you are happy with shell scripting (bash) this can be done. Check this answer as starting point: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58873536/2908599

Comment: Is running the cron and/or updating the Google sheet expensive, and also how current does the sheet need to be? If nothing is expensive, I wouldn't worry too much about how often the cron runs. And if you don't need to be insanely current on the sheet, you can change it from 15 minutes to every hour or two. Otherwise, instead of updating the crontab dynamically, drop a file somewhere (or use a database or whatever) and have your cron script check _that_ to see if an update is needed.

Comment: @ChrisHaas Your instinct is correct. It is not expensive at all and the machine running the cron has only one other task to be a print server for an old laser printer. I'm going to keep it simple and run the cron.

Comment: @RomeoNinov Thanks for the information. When I start having to watch my number of cron calls, I'll follow this approach.